# How to modify Wordpress Custom Post Type URL?

Tags: wordpress, url-routing, custom-post-type

I observed that if I have a custom post type called article, the links become mysite/article/title-of-article-here. How do I make the links to have this pattern -- mysite/title-of-article-here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you define your custom post type, you have to define a "slug." try leaving it undefined, or 'slug' => ''

Comment: Even though I made 'slug' => '' the url of the article still has this pattern: mysite/article/my-article-title

Comment: Now I know how to format the url such that the custom post type does not get prepend. And you are correct, it has to do with the slug. This is what I used for it: 'rewrite' => array('slug' => '', 'with_front' => false),